# How to hold a (self-captured) closure for an observer design model

Tags: rust, design-patterns, closures, lifetime

I am trying to hold multiple callbacks as closures, but I'm having troubles with their lifetime:

```rust
pub type WriteCallback = Box<dyn FnMut(u8, u8) -> u8>;

pub struct AddressBus {
    on_write_listeners: HashMap<usize, WriteCallback>,
}

impl AddressBus {
    pub fn on_write(&mut self, address: usize, callback: WriteCallback) {
        self.on_write_listeners.insert(address, callback);
    }
}

// component.rs

pub struct Component {
    value: u8,
    address_bus: Rc<RefCell<AddressBus>>,
}

impl Component {
    pub fn new(address_bus: Rc<RefCell<AddressBus>>) -> Self {
        Component {
            value: 0,
            address_bus: address_bus.clone(),
        }
    }

    pub fn init(&mut self) {
        self.address_bus.clone().borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF54, Box::new(|old, new| {
            // I want to use self here e.g: self.value = new;
            new
        }));

        self.address_bus.clone().borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF55, Box::new(|old, new| {
            // I want to use self here
            new
        }));
    }
 }
```

But no matter what i try, i always get:

```
32 |       pub fn init(&mut self) {
   |                   - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
33 |           self.address_bus.clone().borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF54, Box::new(|old, new| {
   |  ________________________________________________________________^
34 | |             // I want to use self here
35 | |             self.value = new;
36 | |             new
37 | |         }));
   | |__________^ cast requires that `'1` must outlive `'static`
```

Is there a way to fix this, or do I need to change to a different design pattern? Knowing that I am using wasm-bindgen and can't use lifetime references inside my structures.

I tried to use `move` like `self.address_bus.clone().borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF54, Box::new(move ...`. It works but it also consumes `self` and I am no longer able to use the struct.

Comment: If you want to do this you're going to have to have `init` take something like `Rc<RefCell<Self>>` because (a) there's static no guarantee in your code that the `&mut self` is going to outlive the `AddressBus`, and (b) you can't capture a mutable reference in two closures at once as this violates the aliasing rule. `Rc` solves the first issue and `RefCell` solves the second.

Comment: What do you want to use from `self` there? Do you also want to mutate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work by following cdhowie's advice, using `Rc<RefCell<Self>>`:

```rust
fn init(rc: Rc<RefCell<Self>>) {
    let rc2 = rc.clone();

    rc.clone().borrow_mut().address_bus.borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF54, Box::new(move |old, new| {
        new
    }));
    rc2.clone().borrow_mut().address_bus.borrow_mut().on_write(0xFF55, Box::new(move |old, new| {
        rc2.borrow_mut().value = old;
        new
    }));
}
```

In order to modify `self` in both, I need to clone the reference and move it.